# $a_n=(1+\frac{1}{2})(1+\frac{1}{4})\dots (1+\frac{1}{2^n}) $ converge

Tags: calculus, induction, means

Hi guys I have a problem that i need to prove that the sequence:
$$a_n=(1+\frac{1}{2})(1+\frac{1}{4})\dots (1+\frac{1}{2^n}) $$ converges
I need to show its a monotone sequence with an upper and lower bound.
For lower bound, 0 seems to fit nicely.
I can also see that I always multiply by something bigger than one so its always increasing.
My only issue was finding an upper bound, with my calculator I figured that something around e is the upper bound but I can't prove it.
I attempted by induction:
$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right)\dots\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)<4 $$
after multiplying both sides I got :
$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right)\dots\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)<4\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)<4\cdot2=8 $$
But it seems wrong and Im kind of lost.
Also tried using  $$log_2a_n=log(3)-log(2)+log(5)-log(4)+log(9)-log(8)+\dots log(2^n+1)-log(2^n)$$
No matter how much I try, I just cant prove an upper bound, any suggestions?

Comment: It is pretty excessive to upper bound $1+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ with $2$. Can you use something smaller? Also, how about trying to prove that $\lim a_n \leq 4$ by saying, for example $a_n \leq 4 - \frac{1}{n}$, or something at those lines. If you always use $a_n<4$ and then $a_{n+1}<4 *sth$, it's not going to help.

Comment: Can you see that $$
a_n  = \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {e^{\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{2^k }}} \right)} }  < \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {e^{\frac{1}{{2^k }}} }  = \exp \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{2^k }}} } \right) < \exp \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{2^k }}} } \right) = e?
$$

Comment: I Can see it now.  
Only issue is with the first transition.  
After proving that $ ln(1+x)<x $ for all $ x>0 $ this happens I assume.  
After that it's quite clear, you took an exponent of a partial sum and said its smaller than the infinite sum of a geometric sequence right?

Comment: Exponential is monotone, and the series is strictly increasing.

Comment: Trying to use a uniform bound in a straightforward way won't work here. Your sequence is the same as $$a_{n+1} = \left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right) a_n$$ with $a_0 = 1$. If you bound $a_n$ by a constant, say $M$, then $a_{n+1} < M + \frac{M}{2^{n+1}}$ which doesn't tell you that the $a_m$ have a uniform bound for $m>n$ without a little bit more work (since your bound grows slightly). However I think you can use a little bit of geometric series magic to get there.

Answer (score 5):

In general infinite products are studied via the associated series of logarithms. In other words
$$
a_n = \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1+ \frac{1}{2^i} \right) = \prod_{i=1}^n e^{\log\left( 1+ \frac{1}{2^i} \right)} = e^{\sum_{i=1}^n \log\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)},
$$

and $\sum \log(1+\frac{1}{2^n})$ converges if and only of $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$ converges by the limit comparison test.

More generally, if $x_n\geq 0$ then
$$
\prod_{n=0}^\infty\left(1+x_n\right)\text{ converges if and only if } \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n \text{converges.}
$$

I highly recommend reading the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) on infinite products.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  
I haven't learned about the last rule you mentioned, this question is part of calc 1 homework. 
Do you always take the natural log in these kind of scenarios? Is it pointless to look at logarithms with base 2 like I did for example?

Comment: You are welcome. It is ok to use logarithms in base two, you would just have $2^{\log_2(1+x_n)}$ instead of $e^{\log \cdots}$.

Comment: In general the natural logarithm is always used because it has a nicer relation with respect to the exponential function and derivations/integrations. It is not pointless to try what you did, it's a fair try but it didn't lead you to the solution. However you were close, if you wrote $\log(a_n) = \sum \log_2(1+\frac{1}{2^n})$ and then used a nice bound for the logarithms you would have found the solution. These bounds are also simpler for $\log$ in base $e$, or at least more well known and easier to establish.

Answer (score 2):

Note
\begin{eqnarray}
a_n&=&(1+\frac{1}{2})(1+\frac{1}{4})\dots (1+\frac{1}{2^n})\\
&=&\frac{(1-\frac12)(1+\frac{1}{2})(1+\frac{1}{4})\dots (1+\frac{1}{2^n})}{1-\frac12}\\
&=&2(1-\frac{1}{2^2})(1+\frac{1}{2^2})\dots (1+\frac{1}{2^n})\\
&=&\cdots\\
&=&2(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n}})
\end{eqnarray}
and hence $\{a_n\}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

For the lower bound :

Using Bernoulli's inequality we have $x\geq 0$:

$$(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq 1+\frac{1}{2}x$$

So :

$$(1+\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}(1+\frac{1}{4})^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdots(1+\frac{1}{2^n})^{\frac{1}{2}}< (1+\frac{1}{4})(1+\frac{1}{8})\cdots(1+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$$

Now we can conclude easily